# sql update does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This works

```
SELECT * FROM productinfo a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                FROM productinfo_temp b 
                            WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

However, it would like to update productinfo table from that result

```
UPDATE a SET Deleted = '1' FROM productinfo a 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM productinfo_temp b 
                                WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

But it does not works.
What is wrong with UPDATE?
Here is error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM productinfo a WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM productinfo' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE productinfo a SET Deleted = '1'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM productinfo_temp b 
                                WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `FROM` clause.

```
UPDATE productinfo a 
SET Deleted = '1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                 FROM productinfo_temp b 
                 WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

or simply use this one using `LEFT JOIN`

```
UPDATE  productinfo a 
        LEFT JOIN productinfo_temp b 
            ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
SET     a.Deleted = 1
WHERE   b.ProductID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting in too!

```
UPDATE a SET Deleted = '1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
FROM productinfo_temp  b
WHERE a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```